# Tensorflow MNISTのチュートリアル（バッチ処理について）

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow初心者です．
MNISTのチュートリアルをしているところ以下のようなコードでバッチ処理をしています．

```
for _ in range(1000):
...   batch_xs, batch_ys = [data.spectral,data.labels], batch_size=1000=mnist.train.next_batch(100)
...   sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

チュートリアルのMNISTのデータセットは
mnist.train.images　(画像データ)
mnist.train.labels　(ラベルデータ)
となっているので上記のコマンドが可能ですが，他のデータセットに応用したい場合は
どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

（以下説明が下手ですが具体的に困っている事例です．）
"mnist.train"までは画像データもラベルデータも同じで最後の'images'と’labels’で違う
データセットとなっているため，上記コードでは，mnist.train.next_batch(100)のコードで
実行可能なのだと思います．

自分の生成したデータは，
datax(画像データ)
datay（ラベルデータ）
なのですが，
data.train.x
data.train.y
のように変換する手法がわかりません．

Answer (score 1):

mnistのデータセットは下記のようなnumpy形式になっていますので、お持ちのデータも
同じように[データ数, 画像幅x画像高さ]と[データ数, one hot vector]として
まとめれば実行できると思います。

mnistではデータ数が55000
画像幅x画像高さが784（28x28なので）、
one hot vectorが１０（０から９までの１０クラス分類なので）となってます。

```py
In [1]: from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

In [2]: mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

In [3]: mnist.train.images.shape
Out[3]: (55000, 784)

In [4]: mnist.train.labels.shape
Out[4]: (55000, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

たぶん、mnistのデータセットが特殊で、普通はnumpyかcupyの配列にデータを放り込んでます。
import numpy as np
traindata=np.array(data_x)
的な。どうでしょうか？